# change codeigniter default url format

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

The default url format of codeigniter is `controller/function/params` . Can I change it to `params/controller/function` or `controller/params/function`

Answer (score 1):

You should add routes for the uri scheme you wish to have: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html